# Recycle ListView row based on resource view used?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I made a custom `ArrayAdapter` for my `ListView` that would change the resource view of the row that is clicked on(to simulate a kind of expanding row when you click on it). With a `OnItemClickListener` I watch the click and set the click position to the adapter. I then tell the adapter that the data changed. The adapter then updates, and on the position of the click a different resource view is used, using a simple if statement. The view where the last click occured returns to its initial "unexpanded" state. This is working fine if I just let the Adapter inflate each view from scratch. Here is my code of the `MyAdapter` class I use for this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row;
    LayoutInflater inf = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();

    if(clickposition == position){
        row = inf.inflate(R.layout.expandedoverviewrow, parent, false); 
    }
    else{
        row = inf.inflate(R.layout.overviewrow, parent, false);
    }

    TextView txtPayedby = (TextView)row.findViewById(payedbyId);
    TextView txtAmount = (TextView)row.findViewById(amountId);
    TextView txtDate = (TextView)row.findViewById(dateId);
    TextView txtDescript = (TextView)row.findViewById(descriptId);
    TextView txtPersons = (TextView)row.findViewById(personId);

    txtPayedby.setText(payedbyList.get(position));
    txtAmount.setText(amountList.get(position));
    txtDate.setText(dateList.get(position));
    txtDescript.setText(descriptList.get(position));
    txtPersons.setText(personList.get(position));

    return(row);
}

public void clicked(int position){
    clickposition = position;
}
```

If I however want to recycle views, it is going all wrong. Random row's get the "expanded" view because it is recycling the view's. This is expected if I use the code above. I tried to change the code a bit to differentiate if the `convertView` was either the normal or the "expanded" view. I did this by changing the first part of the code to:

```
View row = convertView; 
    if{row == null || ......){
        LayoutInflater inf = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inf.inflate(R.layout.overviewrow, parent, false);
    }
    if(clickedposition == position){
        LayoutInflater inf = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inf.inflate(R.layout.expandedoverviewrow, parent, false);
    }
```

At the multiple dots in the first if statement I wanted to check if the view was the "expanded" view. I tried all kinds of things, compare the getId with the Resource Id, compare the content description with a string. Compare the convertView with the view that would be created with the inflater. All failed to detect if the view was either the normal or the "extended" view. Resulting in that OS is recycling views, and thus making more and more "expanded" views as rows.

Does anyone knows a method that will work to detect the different views? Or is it better in this case to just don't recycle the views?

Comment: why not just use an `ExpandableListView` with an `ExpandableListAdapter`?  Might make it easier than trying to write your own.

Comment: I dont want to "expand" as in show more information or options, as is done with the ExpandableListView and -Adapter. I actually want to replace the whole row with another when you click on it. And when you click on a other row replace that row and restore the previous row. This is working if I dont recycle the views, I try to find a way to get this working while I do recycle to optimize my app.

Comment: I know this question is pretty old, but I'm wondering if you ever found a solution for it? I'm struggling with a similar issue at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

> ...or is it better in this case to just don't recycle the views?

Always aim to use the `ListView`'s recycle mechanism, below is how I would do it(your logic for implementing the `getView` method is a bit strange). First of all I would use the `getItemViewType` and `getViewTypeCount` method of the adapter. They would look like this:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (clickposition != -1 && position == clickposition) {
        return SPECIAL_VIEW;
    }
    return NORMAL_VIEW;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2; // we have two types of views
}
```

where `NORMAL_VIEW` and `SPECIAL_VIEW` are the two types of rows(the normal one and the expanded one):

```
// fields in your adapter class
public static final int NORMAL_VIEW = 0;
public static final int SPECIAL_VIEW = 1;
```

The using all code above, the `getView` method will look like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int whichOne = getItemViewType(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        switch (whichOne) {
        case NORMAL_VIEW:
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.overviewrow, parent, false);
            break;
        case SPECIAL_VIEW:
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandedoverviewrow, parent, false);
            break;
            }
    } else {
        // there is no else, the getItemViewType will make sure that you have a valid view                    
    }
    // then you would set the data based on the value of whichOne 
    //...
```

When you click an item update the `clickposition` and also call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter so it can adjust the rows.